# Big request on Post or Get in Netty Http

Tags: http, post, netty

I am using Netty for socket connection mainly. But i also want to use netty to handle some http connections as well.
The problem is : the data in the post method sent to Netty Http Server is so large . So Netty raise the exception: Long Frame Exception.
Anyone please tell me how to configure Netty accept bigger Post param value.
Thank you very much

Comment: Which ChannelHandlers you use in the ChannelPipeline ?

Comment: I use the default example of HttpSnoopServer in Netty document.

Comment: Anyway, I changed the solution to websocket instead of Http Server . Thank you for comment @NormanMaurer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have `HttpChunkAggregator` in the pipeline.  Please remove it and handle `HttpChunk` by yourself.

Comment: just curious, why HttpChunkAggregator can't handle large posts?

Comment: @yetanothercoderu I have  had the same issue, using get exceding 4096 size. I have  found that netty raise an exception without handling a 403 error. you can find  the exact issue at  [httpChunkAgregator v3.2 source code](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpChunkAggregator.html) between line 130~135  for the version 3.2 Notice that the TODO indicates there is an known issue.

Comment: Since i'm a beginner with netty architecture I don't have found yet how to implement the TODO